# Hibernate save new one to one entities mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I´m having an issue trying to persist two new entities on database with a mapping between them

The Parent entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "conflictOfInterest") 
@XmlTransient
@JsonIgnore
@Getter 
@Setter 
private RequestForCorrection requestForCorrection;
```

The child entity:

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "conflict_of_interest_id")
@JsonIgnore
@XmlTransient
@Getter
@Setter
private ConflictOfInterest conflictOfInterest;
```

When RequestForCorrection and ConflictOfInterest are ID null and I have

```
requestForCorrection.setConflictOfInterest(conflictOfInterest)
save(requestForCorrection)
```

Hibernate is throwing the exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.greenvalley.etendering.domain.RequestForCorrection.conflictOfInterest -> com.greenvalley.etendering.domain.ConflictOfInterest
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
```

I try change the cascade annotation of the parent to ALL and PERSIST without any success.
I´m looking to save on cascade, so

```
save(conflictOfInterest)
requestForCorrection.setConflictOfInterest(conflictOfInterest)
save(requestForCorrection)
```

I don't consider a valid solution

Comment: I think the join colomn annotation may be placed on on the requestForCorrection field.

Comment: It may depend on what the `save` operation really does. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: @Tony if we change the ForeignKey we have SQL foreign key exception.

Comment: @awb like I describe the save have to persist parent and child on cascade, what else you need to know?

Comment: Its inner representation may be helpful. Otherwise why not just call `entityManager.persist()`?

Comment: Try adding `CascadeType.PERSIST` to your `@OneToOne` mapping

Comment: @Genzotto "I try change the cascade annotation of the parent to ALL and PERSIST without any success."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving the Parent table hibernate it is trying to create the Child table that have a new reference to the parent. I suggest you 2 changes.

First, change the CascadeType from Merge to ALL if you want that all the changes in the parent go to the child

Second, add nullable = false to the Child to force the fk is added in the insert.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "conflictOfInterest")
@XmlTransient
@JsonIgnore
@Getter
@Setter
private RequestForCorrection requestForCorrection;      

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "conflict_of_interest_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
@Getter
@Setter
private ConflictOfInterest conflictOfInterest;
```